# How do I verify this Trigonometric Identity?

Tags: trigonometry

I can't figure out whether to start on the right or left hand side. Anyways here is the question:

$\sin\theta + \cos\theta = \frac{1-2\cos^2\theta}{\sin\theta-\cos\theta}$

Answer (score 2):

\begin{align}
\dfrac{1-2\cos^2 \theta}{\sin \theta-\cos \theta}
&= \dfrac{1-\cos^2\theta-\cos^2\theta}{\sin \theta-\cos \theta} \\
&= \dfrac{\sin^2\theta-\cos^2\theta}{\sin \theta-\cos \theta} \\
&= \dfrac{(\sin \theta-\cos \theta)(\sin \theta+\cos \theta)}{\sin \theta-\cos \theta} \\
&= \sin \theta+\cos \theta
\end{align}

Answer (score 2):

Use cross-products.
$$\sin\theta+\cos\theta = \frac{1-2\cos^2\theta}{\sin\theta-\cos\theta} \implies (\sin\theta+\cos\theta)(\sin\theta-\cos\theta) = 1-2\cos\theta$$
$$\sin^2\theta-\cos^2\theta = 1-2\cos^2\theta$$
$$1-\cos^2\theta-\cos^2\theta = 1-2\cos^2\theta \implies \boxed{1-2\cos^2\theta = 1-2\cos^2\theta}$$
Verified.